# How to use @actions/http-client/auth?

Tags: github-actions

I am using `@actions/http-client` in my GitHub JavaScript action. I would like to provide a `BasicCredentialHandler` as `RequestHandler` to my `HttpClient` constructor. As we can see in [this sample](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/91d3933eb52b351f437151400a88ba7d57442a9b/packages/http-client/__tests__/auth.test.ts#L2) we can use the `BasicCredentialHandler` provided by `@actions/http-client`, but how to import it?

```
import * as httpm from '@actions/http-client';
import * as auth from "@actions/http-client/auth"; // <-- this line does not work

const bch = new auth.BasicCredentialHandler('johndoe','password');
const http = new httpm.HttpClient('my-action', bch);
```

I have the following error while running the script: `Uncaught Error Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '@actions\http-client\auth'`

Comment: I was able to solve it using: `import * as auth from "@actions/http-client/lib/auth.js";`.
Is that the right way to do?